# Merge a lot of DataFrames together, without loop and not using concat

Tags: python, pandas

I have >1000 DataFrames, each have >20K rows and several columns, need to be merge by a certain common column, the idea can be illustrated by this:

```
data1=pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','c','e'], 'value':[1,3,4]})
data2=pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','d','e'], 'value':[3,3,4]})
data3=pd.DataFrame({'name':['d','e','f'], 'value':[1,3,5]})
data4=pd.DataFrame({'name':['d','f','g'], 'value':[0,3,4]})
#some or them may have more or less columns that the others:
#data5=pd.DataFrame({'name':['d','f','g'], 'value':[0,3,4], 'score':[1,3,4]})

final_data=data1
for i, v in enumerate([data2, data3, data4]):
    if i==0:
        final_data=pd.merge(final_data, v, how='outer', left_on='name', 
                            right_on='name', suffixes=('_0', '_%s'%(i+1)))
        #in real case right_on may be = columns other than 'name' 
        #dependents on the dataframe, but this requirement can be 
        #ignored in this minimal example. 
    else:
        final_data=pd.merge(final_data, v, how='outer', left_on='name', 
                            right_on='name', suffixes=('', '_%s'%(i+1)))
```

Result:

```
  name  value_0  value_1  value  value_3
0    a        1        3    NaN      NaN
1    c        3      NaN    NaN      NaN
2    e        4        4      3      NaN
3    d      NaN        3      1        0
4    f      NaN      NaN      5        3
5    g      NaN      NaN    NaN        4

[6 rows x 5 columns]
```

It works, but anyway this can be done without a loop?

**Also**, why the column name of the second to last column is not `value_2`?

---

*P.S.*
I know that in this minimal example, the result can also be achieved by:

```
pd.concat([item.set_index('name') for item in [data1, data2, data3, data4]], axis=1)
```

But In the real case due to the way how the dataframes were constructed and the information stored in the index columns, this is not an ideal solution without additional tricks. So, let's not consider this route.

Answer (score 1):

Does it even make sense to merge it, then? What's wrong with a panel?

```
> data = [data1, data2, data3, data4]
> p = pd.Panel(dict(zip(map(str, range(len(data))), data)))
> p.to_frame().T
major    0          1          2      
minor name value name value name value
0        a     1    c     3    e     4
1        a     3    d     3    e     4
2        d     1    e     3    f     5
3        d     0    f     3    g     4

# and just for kicks
> p.transpose(2, 0, 1).to_frame().reset_index().pivot_table(values='value', rows='name', cols='major')
major   0   1   2   3
name                 
a       1   3 NaN NaN
c       3 NaN NaN NaN
d     NaN   3   1   0
e       4   4   3 NaN
f     NaN NaN   5   3
g     NaN NaN NaN   4
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea indeed. But it works best if there is only one VALUE column, while I have multiple per dataframe (see edit), and the number of columns are not the same across all dataframes. Furthermore, it is actually 2X slower than the loop version, while the loop version is already 2X slower than the `concat` version.

Comment: I was suggesting using the Panel directly, since that seems to be what you're doing already. If it matters which dataframe the data appears to be in, just store that information as an extra column and concat without bothering with the index.